# Lagrange interpolation with zeros at $\pm \infty$

Tags: lagrange-interpolation, pointwise-convergence

Suppose I have a set of $n$ points on the plane at $(x_i, y_i)$, and I want to construct the polynomial interpolating them. This can be done with Lagrange interpolation in the straightforward manner.

Now suppose I add two points at $(a,0)$ and $(b,0)$, where $a < \min(x_i)$ and $b > \max(x_i)$. In other words, I add two zeros, one on either side of the set of points. We can again perform Lagrange interpolation on this augmented set of points to obtain a polynomial that approaches 0 as you approach $a$ and $b$.

This defines a family of polynomials for each choice of $a$ and $b$. I suspect this ought to converge pointwise to some well-defined function (though I haven't proven this).

**Does this converge pointwise to something, and if so, what?**

In effect we end up with Lagrange interpolation, but with extra zeros "at infinity." Does this lead to a well-defined interpolation method?

Comment: At first glance I highly doubt that this gives a convergent sequence of functions.

Comment: Sorry, editing error - meant pointwise. Changed it

Comment: If you have just one point $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0) $, it seems clear that it doesn't converge pointwise.

Comment: I don't see a sequence, only a family parameterized by $a,b$, so you should make clear (in the question, not in a comment) what kind of limit you mean. From the title, one could _guess_ $a\rightarrow-\infty, b\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we write the Lagrange polynomials for the set of points including $a$ and $b$ as $L^{a,b}_j(x)$ and $L_j(x)$ for those without, then they are given by
$$ L^{a,b}_j(x) = \frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{(x_j-a)(x_j-b)}\prod_{i \neq j} \frac{x-x_i}{x_j-x_i} = \frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{(x_j-a)(x_j-b)} L_j(x). \tag{*} $$
Now, since the function values at $a$ and $b$ are zero, the interpolating polynomial is
$$ \sum_j y_j L_j^{a,b}(x), $$
not including $L_a$ or $L_b$. Therefore, every term is of the form in (*), and simple results about rational functions tell us that for fixed $x$,
$$\lim_{\substack{a \to -\infty \\ b \to \infty}} \frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{(x_j-a)(x_j-b)} = 1, $$
so $L^{a,b}_j(x) \to L_j(x)$ pointwise.